# List installed cocoapods and versions

Tags: cocoapods

Does the `pod` command support an option to list the installed CococaPods in a given project? `pod list` appears to display a list of *all* published pods. I've looked around in the documentation but can't find a way of doing this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As stated in [@DougAmos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762241/902968) you should check your `Podfile.lock` to see this information using `cat Podfile.lock`

This doesn't currently exist in CocoaPods. Personally I would just do a `cat Podfile` to learn about what the project was including. I would suggest you create an issue (or even better a pull request) on the [main repository](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) about this!

Comment: Yeah, podfile cat only works if the version is defined - sometimes the version isn't, or it's a `~` or `>`. Will look at doing a pull request.

Comment: Yep! Some of that information is also in the `Podfile.lock` if you're looking for specifically what version CocoaPods installed with the `~>` operator.

Comment: Turns out [`cocoapods-dependencies`](https://github.com/segiddins/cocoapods-dependencies) can do this.

Comment: I am just doing `pod install`

Answer (score 19):

From the root directory of your project:

```
cat Podfile.lock
```

(I know this has been mentioned in a comment, but this should be an answer in it's own right)

Answer (score 4):

`pod outdated` lists installed pods with version numbers and the latest versions available.

Comment: Needed `arch -x86_64 pod outdated ` on my M1 Mac

Comment: This is the best answer. Just shows you the module versions, no scouring through dense lock files.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a little script

```
llpod
```

available [here](https://github.com/velthune/llpod).

Nevertheless, up until now I listed pods with cat:

```
cat Podfile.lock
```

And refine search with grep:

```
cat Podfile.lock | grep Alamo
```

Answer (score -2):

An old question but I still had to find out which version of a pod was installed.

I used the following, it listed everything but in the output is a section like:

```
Downloading dependencies

-> Using AFNetworking (2.7.0)
```

Where I had

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```

In the PodFile